# How to use 2 different iCloud accounts in Reminders app on iOS and macOS?

Tags: macos, icloud, reminders, monterey

I use one iCloud account for my private use (mainly on my phone) and one for work (on my Macbook Pro with Monterey). I however want to use Reminders to use both accounts, so I could see all my working reminders on my private phone and all my private reminders on my working computer. I've already done the same for Calendar but for reminders it seems different. On my Internet Accounts settings page there is no Reminders.
[image]

Am I missing something? Is there a way I can use 2 iCloud accounts in the Reminders?

Comment: this is weird. In my could account there is a check for reminder. So i would guess: yes, it works also with two accounts (although i didn't tried that). Maybe you should check why there is no check for reminder...

Comment: I'm facing the same challenge and want to solve it in a similar way. In the iCloud sync setting on my work MacBook, the Reminder and Notes are greyed out, so they can not be selected to sync. I think this is because my company has set up so that we can not sync Reminder nor Notes to iCloud. Maybe this is your case too?

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question but note that the Reminders app does (sort of) support multiple accounts but only over CalDAV (so you can sync reminders to multiple non-Apple online calendars). Support is limited however (no icons, fewer colors, frequent glitches when updating).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is not supported. There is not documentation from Apple stating one way or another, but the fact that the Reminders app itself does not provide an accounts section while other Apple provided apps, such as Calendar, Mail, etc. all do makes me believe Reminders just was not designed for this.